# glossary explanation of optimal method. Penalty method & Augmented Lagrangian method

Tags: optimization

In the optimization,i believe lots of people heard about Penalty method & Augmented Lagrangian method,but i wonder why are the creators use "penalty" and  "Augmented" to name these method .

Penalty means like punishment,but i can't understand the penalty parameter punish who or which function.

Augment means increase or add,but i can't really understand what does Augmented Lagrangian method Augment,i mean ,Augmented Lagrangian method  should increase or add something to let itself be better than Lagrangian method,but what is that something?

The reason i ask this is because i am afraid of misunderstanding the meaning of Augmented Lagrangian method and Penalty method,because honestly,optimization is abstract to me.

By the way , i saw this question: 
[After reading the quadratic penalty method.i still don't understand what does it actually do,and the time of using it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225440/after-reading-the-quadratic-penalty-method-i-still-dont-understand-what-does-it?fbclid=IwAR3Pv_-ahXAV2ONhFcv6ZwLta7r1E6sDnYVlrugm4tiORHiAE6Bx-ftFDcM)

Someone said the problem is easier to solve for small λ . As λ gets large the solution will lie in a steeper and steeper valley (see your picture above) which makes convergence difficult

However,wiki said The penalty method solves this problem, then at the next iteration it re-solves the problem using a larger value of ${\displaystyle \mu _{k}}$,so if the smaller ${\displaystyle \mu _{k}}$ can let the question easier to solve,why should i use bigger ${\displaystyle \mu _{k}}$ in the next iteration?

Comment: I think [these slides by Nick Gould](http://www.numerical.rl.ac.uk/people/nimg/course/lectures/parts/part5.2.pdf) are a good explanation of both methods. "Penalty" here means a penalty for violating the constraints. "Augmented Lagrangian" means you add something to the Lagrangian of the problem; the thing which you add is again a penalty term.

Comment: @Rahul The penalty explanation you mention is what i want to ask!!! a penalty for violating the constraints,so this "violating" means i combine the constraint with objected functino(so there is no constraint) or i can find the solution but can't not satisfy the constraint

Comment: because this violating means like something dis-obey something,so the parameter disobey the constraint means what?